# How do I change an object's value in EntityFramework before it gets displayed on the web page?

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, webforms, model-binding

I have an ASP.NET webforms webpage that displays a grid of data extracted from a database using EntityFramework and Model Binding. 
There are occasions however when I wish to override the displayed information depending of the value of one of the fields in the data. 
So for example if the field 'hideme' is true then I want to replace the person's name with "Withheld" instead of displaying "Joe Bloggs", which is the value stored in the database.
Note: I do not want to change the value held in database, I just want to intecept it on the way to the web page and alter it's value.

The Webpage grid TemplateField looks like this:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Company" SortExpression="">
    <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text='<%# Item.VehicleKeeper.Name %>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

The code-behind looks something like this (sorry, it's VB!):

```
Public Function VehicleGrid_GetData(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) As IQueryable(Of VehicleKeeperCollection)        Dim mycontext = New RecallContainer()
    Dim myreg As String = "AB01CDE"
    Dim Q1 As IQueryable(Of VehicleKeeperCollection) = From vk In mycontext.VehicleKeeperCollections
                 Select vk
    Q1 = Q1.Where(Function(x) x.Vehicle.Reg = myreg)
    Return Q1
End Function
```

This returns a set of data containing, amongst other things, VehicleKeeperCollection.VehicleKeeper.Name and VehicleKeeperCollection.VehicleKeeper.HideMe

So what I want to do is change the value of VehicleKeeperCollection.VehicleKeeper.Name to "Withheld" if the value of VehicleKeeperCollection.VehicleKeeper.HideMe is true.

The ModelBinding to the grid requires the object I return to be of class "VehicleKeeperCollection" & I thought I might be able to execute the resultant query into evaluated objects, but I don't even seem to be able to do that and maintain the class type.
The code below fails to be able to cast the new object to class VehicleKeeperCollection

```
Dim mynewquery1 As IQueryable(Of VehicleKeeperCollection) = From q In Q1 Select New With 
 {.id = q.id, .VehicleKeeperId = q.VehicleKeeperId, .VehicleId = q.VehicleId, .Vehicle = q.Vehicle, .VehicleKeeper = q.VehicleKeeper}
```

Any pointers as to how I achieve what I want gratefully received, this isn't my area of expertise & I'm struggling!
Thanks

Comment: Hi, have you considered a read only property marked as NotMapped and have a if statement to see if hideme is true or not then return a value based on this condition?

Comment: Hi Karen, I'd be happy to try out what you're suggesting but I've no idea how to achieve it, could you elaborate please? Thanks :)

Comment: I'm posting a GitHub [gist](https://gist.github.com/karenpayneoregon/786073d769202a7e219ba7af9e7a02ab) to show what I mean. Look at ContactTitle and Title properties, Title is the property of interest. If this works I can post in the answer part of your question but refraining at the moment as it's long.

Comment: OK @Karen, I see where you're coming from :)
This application uses Model-First, so unfortunately all the class definitions are generated automatically & I can't change them because they'll just get overwritten the next time the model is complied.
So in the VehicleKeeper.vb file that's generated is the following:

    Partial Public Class VehicleKeeper

        Public Property Company As String

etc. No Get or Set
So is it possible to override the definition of that one property somewhere else so I can add Get & Set as you describe, without losing them again on re-compile?

Comment: Your class is a partial class which means you can create another class in the same namespace in another folder (e.g. PartialClasses) in the project which will only contain the single property so this means if the model is regenerated nothing is overwritten.

Comment: @Karen I've tried modifying the Model-First class definition for that Property with my own custom Get & Set in a similar way to your example & that works so far as I've got. Adding another VehicleKeeper class in another file&folder with the same modified property code causes the error warning that the property has multiple definitions with identical signatures. Fiddling around with Overrides & Overridable doesn't seen to fix the problem. I haven't made the property ReadOnly as this causes the Linq query to fail.

Comment: So did you try setting up a readonly property  with NotMapped annotation? That works as I just tested this (which I knew would work as I do this a good deal)

Comment: I tried Readonly, but where does NotMapped go, I don't see it on your example?

Comment: See https://visualstudiomagazine.com/blogs/tool-tracker/2015/12/suppress-columns-entity-framework-code-first.aspx

Comment: ok, the example you give is code-first & I've got Model-first so I had to delete the field completely from the model (edmx) & add it again in the partial class additional code before it would run. So now I can change the field value from that additional code, but haven't I also stopped it reading the original value from the database? What next?

Comment: Best I can do at this point is to provide a working example to show you how it works, download the following [vs2017 project](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AtGAgKKpqdWjkQg6wMpV-W2nZ1eG?e=0gfhsW), do restored NuGet packages from solution explorer, generate the database via the supplied script. Examine code, run.

Comment: Thanks Karen, I see now that I hadn't understood that you weren't trying to redefine the property that was reading from the database, but rather you are defining new properties in the partial class that you can conditionally copy values to from the original class properties. And now I have that working :)
Unfortunately one of the conditions for whether to change the data is the logged on user's Role & that doesn't seem easy to obtain in the class definition code, nor does it seem the right place to try use it - do you concur?
I'm thinking that the grid's RowDataBound Sub might be better?